# How do I install org.apache.commons.code.binary.Base64?

Tags: java, apache-commons, jdeveloper

I am taking a class on Android and I am a newbie with JDeveloper.  I am working on a Web Services application.  I downloaded some code that has a "Import org.apache.commons.binary.Base64".  JDeveloper is barking "not found" for this import.  I found on the apache website the org.apache.commons.binary.Base64 module and downloaded it.  What do I do now?  I am not sure how or where to place this code.  The downloaded folder has several folders and and way down at the bottom of one of them is my Base64 module.  Sorry for such a basic question. I am using JDeveloper 11g 11.1.1.0.2 running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you downloaded the source, which is just Base64.java, just add it to your project as 
org/apache/commons/binary/Base64.java

If you downloaded a jar, add that to your project classpath. In JDeveloper this should be available from the project properties dialog and select "Libraries\Classpath".

Of course, if you distribute this project it will need to adhere to the Apache license.

Comment: Ok, I got it.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question,

Comment: @Steve Mansfield - if this answer worked for you, you have to mark it as accepted (using the tick below the votes)